# MoveIt Kinematics Solver No kinematics solver instantiated for this group

Tags: ros, kinematics, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I followed the moveit kinematics C++ API because I want to use the inverse kinematics solver. Firstly, I created my own URDF file, followed the tutorial about the MoveIt! Setup Assistant and created the config package for my robot.

The problem appears when I call setFromIK function from my JointStateGroup, the log shows:

```
[ERROR] [1360777186.680515210]: No kinematics solver instantiated for this group
```

And this is my launch file:

```
<launch>

<include file="$(find test_kinematics)/launch/upload_urdf.launch"/>

<node name="test_kinematics" pkg="test_kinematics" type="test_kinematics" respawn="false" output="screen">
 <rosparam name="kinematics_solver" command="load" file="$(find jim_moveit_config)/config/kinematics.yaml"/>
</node>

<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" />

</launch>
```

And my kinematics.yaml file:

```
main_arm:
  kinematics_solver: pr2_arm_kinematics/PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin
  kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
  kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.05
```

main_arm is the name of my JointStateGroup.

Do you know where is my mistake ?

Thanks for your help ;)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55134/moveit-kinematics-solver-no-kinematics-solver-instantiated-for-this-group/) by [arthur_](https://answers.ros.org/users/4192/arthur_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution. I used RobotModelLoader instead of KinematicsModelLoader to load the robot description. KinematicsModelLoader initializes the kinematics solver whereas RobotModelLoader doesn't.

---

Originally posted by [arthur_](https://answers.ros.org/users/4192/arthur_/) with karma: 56 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhangli](https://answers.ros.org/users/28006/zhangli/) on 2016-10-17**:
which header file did you add when using KinematicsModelLoader?

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-07**:
@arthur_ Did the KinematicsModelLoader exist? I don't finde something about it. I have a similar problem.
I have uploaded my urdf, srdf and the kinematics.yaml, but it gives me an error:
No kinematics solver instantiated for group 'arm_1'

It would be great, if you can help me out.